# script that connects to microsoft.Exchange Office365 times out halfway through and prompts for credentials again

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

Client asked me to develop a script that connects to Office365 exchange and scans all users to make sure some mailboxes for apps have access to them. I've got the script developed and it works, but halfway through the script it asks for credentials again. And it says it's creating a new session for implicit remoting.

I've tried creating a New-PSSessionOption -idleTimeout 1200000, which would set the timeout to about 2 hours. That didn't work

I then though my credential object was configured incorrectly, but when I set the $userCredential variable to (get-credential) it does the same thing.

```bsh
$username = ""
$pwdTxt = gc .\SecureStringPassword.txt
$securePwd = $pwdTxt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$UserCredential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $securePwd
$so = New-PSSessionOption -IdleTimeout 1200000
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -SessionOption $so -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

import-PSSession $session

$mailboxes = get-mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited

foreach ($m in $mailboxes) {
"working on $m"

$SmtpAddress = $m.PrimarySmtpAddress;
$Calendar = $SmtpAddress + ":\Calendar"

Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $m.Alias -User mitel-unified-messaging@contoso.com -AccessRights FullAccess -inheritanceType All -confirm:$false;

Add-RecipientPermission $m.Alias -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee mitel-unified-messaging@contoso.com -confirm:$false

Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity $calendar -User courtalert -AccessRights Author -confirm:$false ;

Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $m.Alias -user svcItrezzo@contoso.com -AccessRights FullAccess -inheritanceType All -confirm:$false;

write-host "done with $m" -Foregroundcolor Green
}

Exit-PSSession
```

Expected results - script runs fully without prompting for credentials

actual results - script prompts for credentials, usually at ~2 minutes in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the problem out.  It wasn't much related to my code, but there were a couple of changes I made to the code as well.

First and foremost, the issue was with the Network.  The client's environment was redirecting all port 80/443 traffic to their websense firewall/loadbalancer.  This is what was causing the connections to drop Once I provided the exception, the script ran smoothly.

However, there were a couple of times when the script did not like what I was doing and it would stop the session And this is because of a parameter in

```
import-PSSession $session
```

Once I changed that to

```
Import-PSSession $session -AllowClobber
```

By default, Import-PSSession imports all commands except for commands that have the same names as commands in the current session. To import all the commands, use the AllowClobber parameter.

after all that, the script ran smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using …

```
Import-PSSession $session -AllowClobber
```

… which can get unwieldy at times. Consider using a prefix instead so that you know when you are running EXO vs EXP.

```
    $o365Cred = Get-Credential
    $ExoSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange `
    -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ `
    -Credential $o365Cred `
    -Authentication Basic `
    -AllowRedirection
    Import-PSSession $ExoSession -Prefix Exo


    $ExpSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange `
    -ConnectionUri http://mail.$env:USERDNSDOMAIN/PowerShell/ `
    -Authentication Kerberos
    Import-PSSession $ExpSession -Prefix Exp
```

This way you are not stepping on stuff. Yet, this doe mean that when you use the cmdlet, the prefix must be used.

```
Get-ExoMailbox
Get-ExpMailbox
```

Details are in the help files:

[Import-PSSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-pssession?view=powershell-6)

> -Prefix   Specifies a prefix to the nouns in the names of imported commands.
>
> ***Use this parameter to avoid name conflicts that might occur when different commands in the session have the same name.***
>
> For instance, if you specify the prefix Remote and then import a
>   Get-Date cmdlet, the cmdlet is known in the session as Get-RemoteDate,
>   and it is not confused with the original Get-Date

The examples:
[Adding Exchange Shell items to PowerShell ISE](http://Start-Process%20'https://eightwone.com/2012/10/25/adding-exchange-shell-items-to-powershell-ise')

Comment: Thanks!  However, i'm not familiar with EXO and EXP, are these specific sets of commands for Exchange Online and Exchange On-prem?